# Do placeholder URLs REALLY matter?

Tags: discussion

Short question - I am aware of [RFC2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606), but does it *REALLY* matter if questions and answers use `mysite.com`, `example.com`, `yoursite.com` etc.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say no - not really. Discuss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, until we have a consensus either here, or at the very least across the network as a whole, it categorically does not matter.

This is what RFC2606 actually says about domain names (not TLDs)

> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) also currently has the
>      following second level domain names reserved which can be used as
>      examples.

It then goes on to list example.com, example.net and example.org.

As you can see that's just information, there's no mandate there that all documentation URLs *should* use those domains. It simply states that IANA have *reserved* those domains for use in the manner described.

The most important thing to note is that there''s no mention anywhere that other domains should *not* be used. The RFC is simply saying "Hey, we've got a few domain names reserved for examples if you want them". Nothing more.

A large number of posts were edited last night to change various URLs to conform to those domains listed in RFC2606.

Since we have no policy (across the network or here on DA specifically), those edits were invalid and I've rolled them all back.

Comment: Cool that's what I though. I was gonna roll them back this morning, but as a non-mod I didn't want to create any animosity :)

Comment: Good call, but I don't think there'll be a problem here - it's just a case of a well-meaning editor going a bit too far and implementing a policy without discussing it first. I've had to stop myself just short of doing the same sort of thing tons of times :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say there isn't any requirement to use a specific domain name in the example URLs; maybe example.org (or similar domains) are more convenient to use, but there isn't any need to force users to use a specific domain name, as long as the used domain name would expose the users who click the link to undesired content (see for example xxx.com).

That said, I would also think that edits that are done exclusively to change the domain name used from the example URL should be avoided, especially if the domain name doesn't appear in a clickable link as in the phrase I previously written.
If the post needs to be improved and the example URL is edited to use example.org, that is more acceptable, with one exception: when the answer is referring to a specific URL used by the question. In that case, editing the URL would make the answer more confusing. (Imagine if the question is using mysite.com/node/12 and the answer uses example.com/node/12.)